# All possible combination with the biggest set possible, but limited by a value

Tags: python, combinations

In Python, the itertools.combination module returns empty if the set size given is larger than the size of the possible combinations

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 4))
[]
```

Is there a way to give a limiting size and have the function return the biggest set it can create?
Something like this:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 4))
[(1, 2, 3)]
```

Do I have to verify if the number of items in the collection is smaller than the desired size?

```
if len([1,2,3]) < 4:
    list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], len([1,2,3])))
else:
    list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 4))
```

Comment: I mean, it's trivial to write a wrapper like you did in the question. Are you asking if you can make itertools do this itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], min(4, len([1,2,3])))
```

and indeed, you can write a function to wrap it around:

```
def combinations(items, howmany):
    return list(itertools.combinations(items, min(howmany, len(items)))
```

Comment: I feel dumb about how simple that was. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a `lambda` function (although I'm not sure where the benefits outweigh the use of a normal function)

```
In [118]: import itertools as it

In [121]: max_combs = lambda items, combs: it.combinations(items, min(combs, len(items)))

In [122]: list(max_combs([1,2,3], 4))
Out[122]: [(1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: I feel like it only adds a level of difficulty in comprehension without many benefits.
But TIL it's possible to rename modules imported and how to do a lambda function, so thank you!

Comment: it's just another approach. [adrtam's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55232000/5491375) answer is best